# Implementing rulers in C# form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Does anyone have a good technique (or tutorial) to implement rulers within a C# Windows Forms application? I want to display an image while showing rulers that indicate your mouse position to allow a more accurate positioning of the cursor. Just like the image below:

[image: Ruler depicting where the cursor is located.]

I tried using splitter controls to hold the tick marks but I don't know how to make the top-left the gray blank area. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: I have added my own image due to the image no longer displaying. If the image portrayed is inaccurate, please feel free to rollback the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build a custom control to do this in both X and Y location and use two controls.

The control would have to override `Paint()` and use GDI methods to display the tick marks, it would then capture mouse events and update locations appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best article I've found and used on the matter:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ruler.aspx